# NSOutlineView shows only first 2 levels of the NSTreeController hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm populating a `NSOUtlineView` with a `NSTreeController`.

The `NSTreeController` is a 3 levels hierarchy controller (CBMovie, CBDisc and CBEpisode), but only the first 2 levels are displayed in the outline view.

The implementation is the same for all objects: I've implemented methods to specify children, children count and if the object is a leaf. These methods are correctly called for all objects (also for those ones that are not displayed, the grandchildren: `CBEpisode`).

In the outline View, everything is displayed correctly for the first 2 level. But grandchildren are never displayed, I don't have the option to expand their parent to see them. I can only see CBMovie and CBDiscs.

I'm wondering if there is another setting I'm missing, about how deep the nodes can expand in NSTreeControllers or NSOutlineView configurations.

**Below: Implementation in one of the three nodes.** 
Each node class has different path to its children. This is specified in the -(NSArray*)children method (correctly called).

```
-(NSArray*)children
{
    return [[self Episodes] allObjects];
}

-(int)childrenCount
{
    return [[self Episodes] count];
}

-(BOOL)isLeaf
{
    return ![[self Episodes] count];
}
```

Output of logging code. The datasource, the NSTreeController, seems to have the correct structure.

```
   CBMovie
      CBDisc
         CBEpisode
         CBEpisode
    CBMovie
       CBDisc
       CBDisc
       CBDisc
       CBDisc
    CBMovie
       CBDisc
           CBEpisode
           CBEpisode
```

This is how I populate the NSOutlineView (cell based). I don't use datasource methods, but I'm binding it programmatically.

```
NSMutableDictionary *bindingOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

        if (metadata.valueTransformer) {
            [bindingOptions setObject:metadata.valueTransformer forKey:NSValueTransformerNameBindingOption];
        }
        [bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:NSCreatesSortDescriptorBindingOption];
        [bindingOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:NSRaisesForNotApplicableKeysBindingOption];

        [newColumn bind:@"value" toObject:currentItemsArrayController withKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@", metadata.columnBindingKeyPath] options:bindingOptions];
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: From your description I cannot see any problems. Can you provide some more details, such as the implementation of your tree node?

Comment: @renfei My tree nodes are all inheriting from the same class. What do you need to know more precisely?

Comment: @StefanArentz I've added the only code I'm using for the tree implementation in my tree nodes

Comment: @renfei ok. Indeed that's why I posted it, because I have no clue. What kind of extra details you need? I need some lead

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted my comment. Are you using binding via IB or programmatically? Show us the relevant piece of code or screenshot, like your data structure, `Children`, `Count` or `Leaf` of `NSTreeController`, etc.

Comment: I'm binding via IB: the NSOutlineView to the NSTreeController. Then I've implemented -(NSArray*)children only in all my nodes classes. It seems I don't need the other ones (Count and Leaf) to make it work.

Comment: There is no documented limit on the depth of hierarchies that can be represented by an ``NSTreeController``, so you can rule that out as a possible cause. If you were to post a demo app showcasing the problem, my guess is that you'd have a solution within 30 minutes of making it available. Even if this entails a bit of work on your behalf, it might be worth the effort in the long run. Also, is Core Data in the mix?

Comment: @PaulPatterson Sorry for the delay. Yes, core data is involved, all the tree objects are NSManagedObjects. It's hard to make a demo out of it, because it's a huge project, with complex model database. The code for the NSTreeController is quite simple though. I could create a new project, with new outline view, and create new hard coded NSTreeController, but that wouldn't be the same, I guess.

Comment: I've added the other 2 NSTreeController implementation methods  (children count and leaf) but with the same results.

Comment: When you talk about your 'node classes' what exactly are you talking about? Am I right in thinking that these classes are subclasses of ``NSManagedObject`` and **not** subclasses of ``NSTreeNode``?

Comment: @PaulPatterson No, I've just checked. they are NSTreeControllerTreeNode. If I call representedObject, then I get my NSManagedObject.

Comment: @Patrick: you are describing a strange behavior, as the NSTreeController+NSOutlineView combination should either render all the levels, or render nothing. Do the CBDisk nodes have the expand icons? Also, could you provide the children/childrenCount/isLeaf implementation for all 3 classes and confirm that these three methods are configured in the `attributes inspector` of the tree controller?

Comment: @Cristik No, the CBDisc don't have the expand arrows. I can confirm all methods have been added to all 3 level classes: the methods I've added to the question are those ones in CBDisc, those ones that should work but they are not. They are correctly called. They return the Episodes array. In interface builder, I've correctly specified children, children count and leaf method names: and indeed all methods are called in both Movies and Discs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've figured out why.

Quite stupid: the main outline column containing the disclosure arrows was 20px width only and the arrows of the children had indentation.

I'm using the outline column for the arrows only and not the titles of the nodes, that's why it's so narrow.

I had disabled indentation and now I can see all arrows.

Answer (score 1):

**Examining the `NSTreeController` side**

> The NSTreeController is a 3 levels hierarchy controller, but only the first 2 levels are displayed in the outline view.

Have you confirmed that all three levels are loaded into your `NSTreeController`? You could do this by logging its contents to the console with the extension below. If the output produced by this code matches what appears in your outline-view, the problem is probably on the `NSTreeController` side, not the outline-view.

```
#import "NSTreeController+Logging.h"

@implementation NSTreeController (Logging)

// Make sure this is declared in the associated header file.
-(void)logWithBlock:(NSString * (^)(NSTreeNode *))block {

    NSArray *topNodes = [self.arrangedObjects childNodes];
    [self logNodes:topNodes withIndent:@"" usingBlock:block];
}

// For internal use only.
-(void)logNodes:(NSArray *)nodes
     withIndent:(NSString *)indent
     usingBlock:(NSString * (^)(NSTreeNode *))block {

    for (NSTreeNode * each in nodes) {
        NSLog(@"%@%@", indent, block(each));
        NSString *newIndent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", indent];
        [self logNodes:each.childNodes withIndent:newIndent usingBlock:block];
    }
}

@end
```

The above code does not need to be adjusted, all you need to do is call it with a customised block:

```
-(void)logIt {

    [self.treeController logWithBlock:^NSString *(NSTreeNode * node) {

        // This will be called for every node in the tree. This implementation
        // will see the object's description logged to the console - you may
        // want to do something more elaborate.
        NSString *description = [[node representedObject] description];
        return description;
    }];

}
```

---

**Examining the `NSOutlineView` side**

If all the data seems to have loaded correctly into the `NSTreeController` you could have a look at how your `NSOutlineView` is populated. The delegate method `-[NSOutlineViewDelegate outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item]` is a good place to start. The `item` argument is the `NSTreeNode` instance, so, before you return the relevant view you can look at this node and make sure it's behaving as expected. In your case, you should scrutinize the properties of `item` objects that are representing `CBDisc` objects. (You may need to click on disclosure buttons to get this method to fire for the relevant objects.)

```
-(NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
    viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  item:(id)item {

    NSTreeNode *node = (NSTreeNode *)item;
    NSManagedObject *representedObject = (NSManagedObject *)node.representedObject;

    // Query the node
    NSLog(@"%@ <%@>", representedObject.description, [representedObject class]);
    NSLog(@"  node is a leafNode: %@", node.isLeaf ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"  node has child-count of: %lu", (unsigned long)node.childNodes.count);

    // Query the NSManagedObject
    // your stuff here...

    // This is app-specific - you'll probably need to change the identifier.
    return [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"StandardTableCellView" owner:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. Yes, the NSTreeCOntroller datasource is working correct. I have all children, (I've added to the question the output). But then, when is the issue?? In the NSOutlineView?

Comment: In your question, just above the logging output, you should be explicit about what isn't appearing in the outline view but should be - I'm assuming it's instances of ``CBEpisode``. A screenshot of the ``NSOutlineView`` would also be very helpful. Finally include some information about which ``NSOutlineViewDelegate`` methods you're implementing.

Comment: Yes, CBEpisode are missing.

Comment: I'm impementing several delegate methods. To be honest I should go through them, because that part of the code is old. Is there any delegate method in your mind that could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I've updated my answer regarding a delegate method that might provide useful information.

Comment: Hi Paul, I forgot to mention that I don't use a view-based table view, but a cell-based. So your method is never called.